# postJSON to post request in Javax-rs API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My problem is that even though every thing looks perfect but my JSON request is not reaching service.It looks service is accepting JSON from client.Is there any thing I am missing in my web client.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){

            var url='http://localhost:8080/AlpagoREST/rest/json/metallica/post2/';  
            inputString1 ="{\"location\":\"Location_trial\"}";
            alert(url);
            alert(inputString1);
            $.postJSON = function(url, inputString1, callback) {
                alert("reached here");
                return jQuery.ajax({
                headers: { 
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' 
                },
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': url,
                'data': JSON.stringify(inputString1),
                'dataType': 'json',
                'success': callback
                });
            };

        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This works perfectly when I send post request to same service with postman Chrome plugin and same when I post Json with Rest client from public static void main.

```
    My web service is as below:

        @POST
        @Path("/post2")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response trial(Trial_JSON tjson) {
       System.out.println("reached here in post for Tjson");

       System.out.println("Office Location="+tjson.getLocation());

       String result="Mission done it looks";
            return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();


        }
    -------
```

Trial_JSON is my simple pojo class as below.There is no XML involved over here its only simple JSON and nothng else

```
    public class Trial_JSON {

        private String location;

        public String getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public void setLocation(String location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

    }
```

Comment: It looks service is NOT accepting JSON from client.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors on console

Comment: what does the network tab show for a response from your server?

Comment: small horizontal green line on left nothing else

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a `postJSON` function, but it doesn't look like you ever execute it.

```
       $.postJSON = function(url, inputString1, callback) {
            alert("reached here");
            return jQuery.ajax({
            headers: { 
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' 
            },
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': url,
            'data': JSON.stringify(inputString1),
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': callback
            });
        };
```

Try invoking it with

```
$.postJSON(url, inputString1, function(data) {
    console.log("Done posting");
});
```

Comment: it looks so that control is not reaching to this function...but what all I can change to make it execute...is it not at its expected location?

Comment: It's not reaching inside the function because you have only defined it. You must invoke the function. I edited to include an example invocation. Add it right below the definition.

Comment: Thanks Samuel ! It moved ahead from that but not got another exception in logs as below:SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with path [/AlpagoREST] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
 at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)

Comment: Okay that's progress! You should create a new question with your exception in it so it gets better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try making these two changes:

```
inputString1 ='{"location":"Location_trial"}';

'data': inputString1,
```